# PHP callbacks usage

Tags: php, design-patterns, callback

I know what the callbacks are and how works, I'm just thinking about **WHEN** to use them.

What are you typical situations where you use a callback?

Are there any design patterns or something like this for these situations?

Thank you.

*Edit:*

I don't want to use callbacks instead of OOP. I was thinking about methods in your PHP class which accepts for some reason a callback as an argument besides its other arguments. Methods like this for example: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L465 or https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L784.

I think this is the legit question. Take a look at the methods to see what I mean as a callback. I'm just asking about some examples when you use callbacks. If you have some use cases which do you solve with callbacks.

Comment: This is my opinion: Basically callback functions were incorporated in PHP in the time when OOP was not possible in PHP. Use them when you need to, but otherwise try to avoid them.

Comment: You pretty much just use one when you need to call a function that takes a callback. I don't think they inherently have anything to do with design patterns.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Why would you try to avoid callbacks?

Comment: @Don't Panic: It's better to use OOP than to use callbacks, for many, many, reasons. So, if you want to write code that is up to 'some standard', it is not useful to start creating functions that need callbacks.

Comment: So, for many, many reasons. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: an example : https://eval.in/783421

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I don't want to use callbacks instead of OOP. I was thinking about methods in your PHP class which accepts for some reason a callback as an argument besides its other arguments. Methods like this for example: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L465 or https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L784.